# Why Room Database does not show changes after running update query?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

i have very interesting problem with updating my column in room database. i am using mvvm architecture and coroutines for handling this. so problem that is my update method work  but i cant see changes in my database via sqlbrowser .
when i run update query i can show the result in my live data in activity but when i copy and open my databse in sqlbrowser my db has no changes but i can see change in my activity livedata. also after i close my app and run again i see changes in my activity but still no change in sqlbrowser. tip is when i run query  size of "wal file" in my database path in emulator is increase and when reached to above 400kb i can see changed item in sqlbrowser!!!

my questions is :

1- if my data in databse is not change so why can i see this change in my activity?

2- if data is changed why i cant see this change in my database file via sqlbrowser?

3- at the end What is the connection between "wal file" and Apply changes to databse ?

and this is  that i say : [database wal file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rf59.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the case you defined should not happen as you can see data update in your app.Try closing your `Device File Explorer` after updating the data and then download the db file.

This is what i use

Declare below in your gradle file to check live updates

> debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'

[Documentation](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database)

Or

[Android studios database inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database)

Comment: with Android studios database inspector i see live change and its correct but with copy/paste from Device File Explorer problem still here. i dont know why but i think best why for managing database is using Android studios database inspector for see live change.tnx @Anmol